# smtp::sendmessage gives "400: premature end-of-file from server" when attempting to mail certain attachments

Tags: smtp, tcl

Very occasionally our TCL application fails to send an email which has attachments. I have 3 example files that I can consistently reproduce this issue with (a PDF, a DOCX and a PPTX). I have put together the following test case to reproduce this issue in a TCL shell (on Windows 2012, I haven't tried other OSes). The PDF file [can be downloaded here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0rjcndbgyi3o6bl/Raptor+1NT.pdf/file).

To reproduce the issue download the above PDF file and save it on your local drive e.g. "c:/tmp/Raptor 1NT.pdf". Save the following code to a new TCL file in a local temp directory e.g. c:/tmp/mail-fail.tcl. Edit the code to change the `filename` variable to the location of where you saved the PDF. You should also change the `smtpHost` and `smtpport` as appropriate. In the TCL shell source the script to run it e.g. `source c:/tmp/mail-fail.tcl` (Note, I've just updated the test case to use mime 1.6 and smtp 1.4.5).

```
package require mime 1.6
package require smtp 1.4.5
#package require mime 1.4
#package require smtp 1.4

proc mail_test { } {

    set filename "c:/tmp/Raptor 1NT.pdf" ;#change this to wherever you saved the file    
    set smtpHost 192.168.1.7 ;#change these to your smtp host and port
    set smtpport 25

    puts "Start\n"
    set from_addr "anyone@anywhere.com"
    set originator "bounce-555-9C2589AD35AF0A6CF851CACA5555AA1741C3E2C6-9066@anywhere.com"
    set reply_to $from_addr
    set to_addr $from_addr
    set mime_type "application/pdf"
    set title "Raptor PDF"
    set name "=Raptor 1NT.pdf"


    set tokens [mime::initialize \
        -param [list name  $title] \
        -header [list "Content-Disposition" "attachment; filename=\"$name\""] \
        -header [list Content-Description $title] \
        -canonical $mime_type \
        -file "$filename"]

    set tokens [mime::initialize -canonical "multipart/mixed" -parts $tokens]

    set message_id [mime::uniqueID]
    mime::setheader $tokens "message-id" $message_id

    set clock [clock seconds]
    set date [clock format $clock -format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"]
    set message_date [mime::parsedatetime $date proper]        
    mime::setheader $tokens date $message_date

    set encoded_subject "=?UTF-8?Q?My_test_mail?="
    mime::setheader $tokens Subject $encoded_subject

    set headers_list [list [list From $from_addr]  [list Reply-To $reply_to]  [list To [join $to_addr ","]]]
    set cmd [list smtp::sendmessage $tokens -originator $originator]
    foreach header $headers_list {
        lappend cmd -header $header
    }
    lappend cmd -servers $smtpHost -ports $smtpport
    puts "cmd=$cmd \n"

    if {[catch $cmd errorMsg]} {
        puts "\n$errorMsg \n" 
    } else {
        puts "Mail successfully sent \n" 
    }

    puts "\nThe end." 
}

mail_test
```

The output that I'm getting when I run this script is:

```
cmd=smtp::sendmessage ::mime::27 -originator bounce-555-9C2589AD35AF0A6CF851CACA5555AA1741C3E2C6-9066@anywhere.com -header {From anyone@anywhere.com} -header {Reply-To anyone@anywhere.com} -header {To anyone@anywhere.com} -servers 192.168.1.7 -ports 25

400: premature end-of-file from server
```

Now this application has been successfully sending 1000s of emails with attachments for years, but these few examples that I have found are just not sending.

Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: Thanks for providing a viable script for reproducing ... that said, I cannot reproduce the misbehavior you are experiencing. I tested with Tcl 8.6.10 and mime 1.6.2, against a local SMTP server (Python SMTP DebuggingServer). All is fine, I get: ```Start

cmd=smtp::sendmessage ::mime::2 -originator bounce-555-9C2589AD35AF0A6CF851CACA5555AA1741C3E2C6-9066@anywhere.com -header {From anyone@anywhere.com} -header {Reply-To anyone@anywhere.com} -header {To anyone@anywhere.com} -servers 127.0.0.1 -ports 25 

Mail successfully sent ```

Comment: Bottom line: Better spend the time in upgrading your tcllib installation.

Comment: @mrcalvin thanks very much for taking the time to test, that's very useful information. I will try more recent versions. By the way what version of smtp are you using?

Comment: I've just updated my test case to use mime 1.6 and smtp 1.4.5 - the problem is still happening. I wonder if it's just an issue with our mail server? I will try the Python SMTP DebuggingServer you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I tried the Python SMTP DebuggingServer (python -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -n localhost:8025) and same as you,I got Mail successfully sent, with both my original package versions and the more recent versions. So what's the conclusion? That the mail server is somehow rejecting the file? I've used the same mail server to send the same file with Outlook, so I'm still puzzled. Any ideas?

Comment: What mail server are you using then exactly?

Comment: Ok, one more update. I managed to find an installation using a different mail server, and the issue doesn't happen there. So I think that's the end of the road. Thanks very much again for the help!

Comment: Could you self-answer then the question?

Comment: Yes, I will once I have explored our mail server logs a bit more - at first glance, it appears to be the firewall killing the channel from TCL to mail server, possibly due to some suspicious content in the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes here wondering what the solution was, the issue here turned out to be a firewall rule that was blocking the attachment. Lesson learned - check your logs when you have mail problems!